# How to prove that the first or a free column must be the linear combination of the previous columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

For example, the matrix is
$$
    \left [\begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & -2 & 2 & 5 \\
    0 & 3 & -3 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix}\right ],
$$

and after elimination, it is
$$
    \left [\begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & -2 & 2 & 5 \\
    0 & 3 & -3 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{3} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix}\right ].
$$

The 3rd and 4th columns are free columns, and they are definately linear combinations of left columns.

How to prove it?

Comment: Hint: This is equivalent to solving a system of linear equations, what tools to do you know from linear algebra that provide a systematic approach to such problems?

Comment: I still can not get it, can you please explain it in more detail?